# Create only 1 instance of handler in entire app

Tags: android, kotlin

I created a `Handler()` in my onCreate method of my MainActivity to run some code, so obviously everytime onCreate gets called, a new instance of my handler is created. When user navigates away from MainActivity and then comes back to it, a new handler is created.

```
handler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            try {
                player.money += player.cps
                player.moneyEarned += player.cps
                updateText()
                save()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("ERROR")
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
        }
    }, 0)
```

How do I make it so that a new handler is not created when navigating back to my MainActivity? Or somehow get this handler to run at a global application level which means only one instance of it will ever be created?

Info:
Creating too many of these handlers caused my app to lag, then crash. Too many read and write and calculation operations I guess. I discovered this after navigating away from MainActivity more than 50 times.

Comment: Each thread can have its own `Handler` . So when you call it from Ui thread you will get a `Handler` with `MainLooper` which is equivalent to `new Handler(getMainLooper())` . So for using in same thread for exa in `MainThread` you can create a `MainThreadHandler` Utility class.

Comment: I don't even know which thread my handler is running on, I'm guessing it is already on main thread since I did not create a thread.

Comment: You can use a singleton approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398072/singleton-with-parameter-in-kotlin

Comment: Default constructor associates this handler with the Looper for the current thread. So in your case it must be main Thread.

Comment: You can create a `Handler` in application class and access it throughout the app .

Comment: @ADM An application can be considered as a singleton?

Comment: Yeah In a way . Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826905/singletons-vs-application-context-in-android.

Comment: Are you using weak reference for the activity inside the handler? If not could it be a garbage collection issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your `Application` class, so you will have only one holder, you can also make it `static`.

In order to extend Application:
1. Create App class `public class App extends Application`
2. In your `manifest` under `application` tag set `name=".App"`

There is `onCreate` method which can be used for that purpose

Comment: The thing you said to do to the manifest does not work. name=".App" goes up in error.