# Singleton class in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to know how to create a singleton class in Kotlin, so that my Util class instantiates it only once per app execution. However, when I converted my Java class to kotlin, the code below was generated.

**Is this correct?**

```
companion object {
    private var utilProject: UtilProject? = null

    val instance: UtilProject
        get() {
            if (utilProject == null) utilProject = UtilProject()
            return utilProject!!
        }
}
```

I could find a related **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40398072/6891563)**, but it is with parameters, and I am not getting it convert without params.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Just

```
companion object {
    val instance = UtilProject()
}
```

will do the job because the *companion object* itself is a language-level singleton.
(The `instance` will be created when the companion object is *first* called.)

-- Updated --

If you need to control when the singleton object is initialized, you can create one object for each class.

```
class UtilProject {
    ....
    companion object {
        val instance = UtilProject()
    }
}

class AnotherClass {
    ...
    companion object {
        val instance = AnotherClass()
        const val abc = "ABC"
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = UtilProject.instance // UtilProject.instance will be initialized here.
    val b = AnotherClass.abc // AnotherClass.instance will be initialized here because AnotherClass's companion object is instantiated.
    val c = AnotherClass.instance
}
```

Here, `AnotherClass.instance` is initialized before `AnotherClass.instance` is actually called. It is initialized when `AnotherClass`'s companion object is called.
To prevent it from being initialized before when it is needed, you can use like this:

```
class UtilProject {
    ....
    companion object {
        fun f() = ...
    }
}

class AnotherClass {
    ...
    companion object {
        const val abc = "ABC"
    }
}

object UtilProjectSingleton {
    val instance = UtilProject()
}

object AnotherClassSingleton {
    val instance = AnotherClass()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    UtilProject.f()
    println(AnotherClass.abc)

    val a = UtilProjectSingleton.instance // UtilProjectSingleton.instance will be initialized here.
    val b = AnotherClassSingleton.instance // AnotherClassSingleton.instance will be initialized here.

    val c = UtilProjectSingleton.instance // c is a.
}
```

If you don't care when each singleton is initialized, you can also use it like this:

```
class UtilProject {
    ....
    companion object {
        fun f() = ...
    }
}

class AnotherClass {
    ...
    companion object {
        const val abc = "ABC"
    }
}

object Singletons {
    val utilProject = UtilProject()
    val anotherClass = AnotherClass()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = Singletons.utilProject
    val b = Singletons.anotherClass 
}
```

In summary,
an `object` or a `companion object` is one singleton object in Kotlin.
You can assign variables in an *object* or *objects*, and then use the variables just like they were singletons.

`object` or `companion object` is instantiated when it is first used.
`val`s and `var`s in an `object` are initialized when the `object` is first instantiated (i.e., when the `object` is first used).

**EDIT**:
William Hu said in the comment that "a `companion object` is when the class is loaded."

Comment: Are all objects inside `companion` singleton?

Comment: @Khemraj No. The `companion object` is one singleton object. If you need many different singletons, you can create many objects for each singleton. I will update the answer.

Comment: Good explanation !, Still I need a year to understand this new language syntax.

Comment: That's not the best answer, because the best way to create a util class is to use object keyword in place of class keyword - then it is a language level singleton, and we don't have to bother with creating an instance of such a class. We just use functions the same way as Java's static methods. Please see my answer

Comment: ```The companion object is one singleton object. If you need many different singletons, you can create many objects for each singleton.``` - hehe, nice joke bro

Comment: What about INITIALIZATION of the singleton? If `ojbect` can't have a constructor, should we use an initializer block (`init {...}`)?

Comment: `object or companion object is instantiated when it is first used` this isn't correct, `object` is, but `companion object` is when the class is loaded.

Answer (score 109):

There is a special keyword `object` for singletons in Kotlin. You can just type something as simple as this to get working singleton class:

```
object MySingleton
```

or when you want some member functions:

```
object MySingleton {
    fun someFunction(...) {...}
}
```

And then use it:

```
MySingleton.someFunction(...)
```

there is a reference: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations

**EDIT:**

In your case, you just need to replace in your definition of `class UtilProject` to this:

```
object UtilProject {

    // here you put all member functions, values and variables
    // that you need in your singleton Util class, for example:

    val maxValue: Int = 100

    fun compareInts(a: Int, b: Int): Int {...}
}
```

And then you can simply use your singleton in other places:

```
UtilProject.compareInts(1, 2)
//or
var value = UtilProject.maxValue
```

Comment: I did not get this. How can this be useful for my Util class?

Comment: against creating `companion object`, just change declaration of `class UtilProject` to `object UtilProject`

Comment: Like @Naetmul answer?

Comment: actually, using `object` instead of `class` is your singleton. The [mentioned reference above](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations) is worth reading ;-)

Comment: Using `object` instead of `class` is the most optimized solution. If you want to call a method inside your object from a JAVA class you can use `Singleton.INSTANCE.methodeName()..`

Answer (score 14):

Super simple lazy example:

```
companion object {
    val instance: UtilProject by lazy { UtilProject() }
}
```

Comment: dont needed!
just use object keyword

Comment: True. Actually, the object keyword does the same

Answer (score 8):

Only the word object is needed.

```
object UtilProject {
    var bar: Int = 0
    fun foo() {        
    }
}
```

And you directly access the object that has only one instance

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    UtilProject.bar = 1
    println(UtilProject.bar)    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 class TestMySingleton private constructor() {
​
   companion object {
        var single = TestMySingleton()

        fun getInstance(): TestMySingleton {
            if (single == null)
                single = TestMySingleton()
            return single
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will help. I am using `Dialog` class, but you can use the example for the idea on how to implement.

```
class MyClass(context: Context) : Dialog(context) {
    companion object {
    lateinit var INSTANCE: MyClass

    @JvmStatic
    fun getInstance(context: Context): MyClass{
        if (!::INSTANCE.isInitialized) {
            INSTANCE = MyClass(context)
        }

        return INSTANCE
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

A `Singleton` example over retrofit to support the api call.

```
object RetrofitClient {

    private var instance: Api? = null
    private val BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"

    fun getInstance(): Api? {
        if (instance == null) {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
            instance = retrofit.create(Api::class.java)
        }
        return instance
    }
}
```

Comment: The way you're implementing the `getInstance()` method is not correct. The logic inside `getInstance()` says it will always return `non-null` value yet your return type (`Api?`) says it can return `null` value. If you try to refactor return type to `Api` you'll get `Smart cast to a mutable property is not possible` warning.

Comment: This is a flawed implementation. It's missing synchronization. There's also no reason it should have to return a nullable.

Answer (score 2):

Variant with parametrs

```
open class SingletonHolder<out T: Any, in A>(creator: (A) -> T) {
    private var creator: ((A) -> T)? = creator
    @Volatile private var instance: T? = null

    fun getInstance(arg: A): T {
        val checkInstance = instance
        if (checkInstance != null) {
            return checkInstance
        }

        return synchronized(this) {
            val checkInstanceAgain = instance
            if (checkInstanceAgain != null) {
                checkInstanceAgain
            } else {
                val created = creator!!(arg)
                instance = created
                creator = null
                created
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A great answer but it's only a part of the whole thing. This code is copied from here:
https://blog.mindorks.com/how-to-create-a-singleton-class-in-kotlin Take a look to get the whole picture and why this is the way to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass {


    init {
        println("init is called")
    }

    companion object {

        private var obj: MyClass? = null
        fun getInstance(): MyClass {
            if (obj == null) {
                obj = MyClass()
            }
            return obj as MyClass 
        }

    }

    fun printHello() {
        println("Hello World")
    }
```

You can create its instance by  `MyClass.getInstance()` something like java

Answer (score 0):

All the answers here are mostly correct except when thread handling comes. My use case was this

Calling both methods at the **same time** with **different threads**:

```kotlin
private fun getProductListSync() {
    launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        products = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { getProducts() }
    }
}

private suspend fun getProducts(): List<Product>? {
    val client = APIUtils.getClient() // this method is used for getting Retrofit Client
    val productListCall = client.create(APIBuilder::class.java).getProductList()
    return if (productListCall.isSuccessful) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

```kotlin
private fun getRestaurantDetailsSync() {
    launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        storeInfo = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { getStoreInfo() }
    }
}

private suspend fun getStoreInfo(): StoreInfo? {
    val client = APIUtils.getClient()
    val storeInfoCall = client.create(APIBuilder::class.java).getStoreInfo()
    return if (storeInfoCall.isSuccessful) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Calling Code**:

```kotlin
getRestaurantDetailsSync()
getProductListSync()
```

Correct code for APIUtils for singleton pattern for multiple thread handling

APIUtils.kt

```kotlin
object APIUtils {

    @Volatile
    private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

    /**
     * You can create multiple methods for different BaseURL
     *
     * @return [Retrofit] object
     */
    @Synchronized
    fun getClient(): Retrofit {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.API.BASE_URL)
                .build()
        }
        return retrofit!!
    }

    fun destroy() {
        retrofit = null
    }
}
```

Note: Here, if we don't use @Volatile on field and @Synchronized on function it will create multiple copies of retrofit field when called from different threads.

You can also reassign retrofit client to apply additional static headers because we used **"var"** keyword instead of **"val"** or **"lateinit var"**