# Singleton with isInitialized check

Tags: android, kotlin

I´m developing a singleton class in Kotlin but I want check if the lateinit var "instance" is Initialized instead check if is null but It doesnt work. I think is better init the var like lateinit and no like null var.

```
companion object {
    private lateinit var instance: GameDAO

    fun getInstance(): GameDAO {
        if (!::instance.isInitialized) {
            synchronized(this) {
                instance = GameDAO()
            }
        }
        return instance
    }
}
```

The compiler show me the next error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewMB9.png)

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/51834996/6891563

Comment: kotlin already has object for singleton, no need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're trying to achieve can best be done using the `lazy` function to lazily initialise a value when first requested.  See [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/lazy.html) for details.

e.g.

```
companion object {
    val instance: GameDAO by lazy { GameDAO() }
}
```

You don't need a separate `getInstance` function: you can just access the `instance` property directly, and it'll be initialised on first request (in a thread-safe way).

This is assuming that you only want the object to be initialised when first requested (i.e. lazily initialised). If you want it to always be created then you can just construct it and assign it to a variable/property immediately.

Comment: Better use `by lazy` instead of `= lazy` (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy).

Comment: Agreed, thanks @AlexeyRomanov. Have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: What if there is no default constructor available?

Comment: You don't need to use a default constructor. The code in the lambda you pass to `lazy` can access whatever variables are in scope, so can use those to construct an object that needs parameters. (Obviously those variables need to be initialised themselves too.)

Answer (score 0):

```
object GameDao {
    fun hereGoesYourFunctions()
}
```

calling hereGoesYourFunctions will initialize the GameDao class.

Answer (score -1):

You may try even better approach :

```
class SingletonClass private constructor() {

init {
    println("This ($this) is a singleton")
}

private object Holder {
    val INSTANCE = SingletonClass()
}

companion object {
    val instance: SingletonClass by lazy {
        Holder.INSTANCE
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this isn't a better approach at all in Kotlin.