# Android/Kotlin: I try to create a simple Singleton, but when I want to use it, it doesn't import the class in the class I want to use

Tags: android, kotlin, import, singleton

I would like to create a singleton to access some functions, but when I import it, It doesn't find the class to import:
[image]

**Class with singleton:**
 DBHandler.kt

```
    package com.xxxxx.GMP_app_android.DBManagement

    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
    import android.content.Context
    import android.content.ContentValues
    import android.content.ContentResolver
    import com.NewTelApps.GMP_app_android.DBLocal
    import com.NewTelApps.GMP_app_android.DBServer
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.view.View

    class DBHandler : AppCompatActivity() {
        var sharedManager: DBHandler? = null

        fun createInstance(): DBHandler {
            if (sharedManager == null) {
                sharedManager = DBHandler()
            }
            return sharedManager!!
        }

        fun getInstance(): DBHandler? {
            if (sharedManager == null) createInstance()
            return sharedManager
        }


        fun methodToSelectData(strQuery: String, dataBase: String)/*, completion: @escaping (_ result:*/
        {
    /*        val dbLocal = DBLocal(this, null, null, 1)
            dbLocal.methodToSelectData(strQuery)*/
        }

        fun methodToInsertUpdateDeleteData(strQuery: String)/*, completion: @escaping (_ result: Bool) -> Void)*/
        {

        }
    }
```

**Usage in another class:** 
 Impossible to access to getInstance()

```
DBHandler.getInstance().methodToSelectData("SELECT * FROM TABLE")
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is a Singleton, then it shouldn't expect AppCompatActivity. If this is a Singleton, I don't know why it doesn't just use `object` from Kotlin, considering this is Kotlin code.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I tried some code, I think I let it by mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how that works in Kotlin. In your code, `getInstance()` is a regular method that needs an instance of your `DBHandler` class. So that method is not static and cannot be called like you're trying to do.

`object` is the default way of doing singletons in Kotlin. But if you want something more powerful and need an instance, have a look at those: [Singleton class in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51834996/singleton-class-in-kotlin)

Basically you return an instance of the class from a `companion object`.

BTW, why does your `DBHandler` extends `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: I tried many things, I put it to try I think, no particular reason

Comment: BTW, your canonical path is `com.NewTelApp.GMP_app_android.DBManagement.DBHandler` not `com.NewTelApp.GMP_app_android.DBHandler`

Comment: @ shkschneider Yep, I just saw that :D That was the two problems