# Single instance of firebase

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

How to get single instance of firebase in android throughout application.
Iam getting instance from class.whlie trying to do from module level am getting fail.

```
Class firebasemodule{
     Var module = module{ 
   singlee(createdatstart=true){ 
     gett<Firebase>().instance}}
}
In app level class
Startkoin{ module(listof(firebasemodule))}
```

Here am getting error.

Any suggestion accepted and I would be helpful for me and for many also.

Comment: could you fix the syntax in your example first? e.g. `class` `single` `get` etc..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Singleton class in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51834996/singleton-class-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
class FirebaseModule {
    val module = module {
        single {
            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's simple and very quick  solution

Comment: If don't want to take instance in this module , we can create seperate 
class for firebase and call that class in module.

'''     class FirebaseModule {
    val module = module {
        single {
            FirebaseHandler()
        }
    }
}
Class FirebaseHandler(){
Firebase.getInstance().
}     '''

Answer (score 0):

If don't want to take instance in this module , we can create seperate
class for firebase and call that class in module.

```kotlin
class FirebaseModule {
    val module = module {
        single {
            FirebaseHandler()
        }
    }
}
class FirebaseHandler(){
   val firebase = Firebase.getInstance()
}
```