# Android: How to create only one instance of DatabaseRepository.kt and use it in different activities?

Tags: android, kotlin, repository, singleton, android-jetpack-datastore

`EDIT: I NEED TO PASS A CONTEXT AS A PARAMETER TO THE CLASS`

(`DataStore` and `repository` is the same class, don't get confused)

I have two activities, `A` and `B` and one `repository`. Activity `A` opens activity `B` and activity `B` saves data in the `repository`(`DataStore` a part of android jetpack).

I am using `LiveData` in both the activities to observe data change in the `DataStore`.

After updating new values in the `DataStore` from activity `B`, the `LiveData` in the activity `B` gets new updated values as expected. But when i return back to activity `A` the `LiveData` gets the old the data (expecting the new updated data).

I realized that it is happening because i am creating two instances of the `repository` in both the activities.

How can i create only one instance of the `repository` class and use it in both the activities? If there's better way to do it then that solution is also welcomed.

Comment: The concept you are looking for is called singleton class. Make repository a singleton class. For reference have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51835156/10817890

Comment: I didn't find a proper way to create singleton class in `kotlin` that can also receive parameters. How can i do that?

Comment: `I need to pass parameters to the class.` this is information you need to add to your question. that's why just writing lots of text doesn't help,  you need to include something others can recreate

Comment: Sorry, I am adding that to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single instance based on static reference and passing `Context` as class parameter causes memory leak. In other hand you can use `Application` class to create one instance of required class

```
class YourApp : Application(){
    val repository by lazy { YourRepository(this) }
}
```

and access it elsewhere with `(context.applicationContext as YourApp).repository`. And don't forget to declare `android:name=...` for application at manifest

Answer (score 3):

While traditional singleton pattern like @DanBaruch mentioned works, but `Kotlin` has awesome keyword called `object` by which you can create singleton instance through out the app.

```
object DatabaseRepository{
    private lateinit var context: Context

    fun setAppContext(context: Context){
        this.context = context
    }
}
```

To set the `context` from `Application` class do below,

```
DatabaseRepository.setAppContext(this)
```

Comment: I need to pass parameters to the class.

Comment: What do you want to pass, you can still directly variables in object as it is singleton

Comment: I need to pass a context

Comment: Ideally  you can create a context variable inside `DatabaseRepository` and set it using `DatabaseRepository.context = context`, but it is never never never a recommended approach not only in this case but for any singletons because singleton variable has lifecycle of App meaning it will keep your context alive which is bad and using context in repository will couple repository with Android Framework there by hard to unit test.

Comment: What if i pass `applicationContext` instead of `activity context`?

Comment: You can do that, as it anyways stays alive through out the app lifecycle

Comment: If you modify your answer to use `applicationContext` i will accept this answer.

Comment: I will first test it and if it works then i will accept it. Thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

In kotlin, there are 2 ways tto create a `Singleton`.

1. Use an `object` keyword - With this, we can have any arguments in the constructor.
2. Or we can create a singleton class, like this:

```
class DbRepository () {

    companion object {
        private var instance: DbRepository? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): DbRepository {
            return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: DbRepository().also { instance = it }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Singleton design pattern?
If so:

```
class DataSource private constructor(private var mP1: Any?, private var mP2: Any?) {

fun setParam1(p1: Any) {
    mP1 = p1
}

fun setParam2(p2: Any) {
    mP2 = p2
}

companion object {
    private var mInstance: DataSource? = null
    fun getInstance(p1: Any, p2: Any): DataSource {
        if (mInstance == null)
            mInstance = DataSource(p1, p2)
        return mInstance
    }
}
}
```

I wrote this mockup in Android Studio and converted it to kotlin, I have no clue if it's valid code in Kotlin.

There are 2 options, either you send parameters to getInstance at the very first time you call that function and afterwards you call it with nulls
as in:

```
//First time calling:
DataSource mMyInstance = DataSource.getInstance(param1, param2);
 //Second time calling:
 DataSource mMyInstance2 = DataSource.getInstance(null,null);
```

Or use setting functions and keep your getInstance with no params.
Do note that choosing option 1 makes you call getInstance with useless params but makes sure you don't forget to set any needed parameter while choosing option 2 maybe have a cleaner "getInstance" call but will force you to always set the parameters which, in my opinion, is the worse option of the 2

Comment: I need to pass parameters to the class and i am using kotlin

Comment: I don't know Kotlin and I don't know how to convert it to Kotlin, but from what I've read around it seems rather easy, anyway, I'll update the code to give the option to provide parameters and you'll use the one that fit your needs the most. Regarding converting it, I think there's a tool in Android Studio to do so

Answer (score 0):

Since the object keyword does not allow parameters, I would suggest to use dependency injection like Dagger/Hilt to create a singleton and inject it to your viewmodels.

The [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android) is worth reading to get started.

If you have no experience with dependency injection frameworks yet, you should read about the topic first and then decide if you want to integrate DI into your apps code.