# Repository returning flow from a room database using kotlin flows

Tags: android, repository, android-room, kotlin-flow

This is a bug I have "fixed" but I want to know why and what is going on.

Initially, I had a single room database instance, which is used to initialize a single repository instance. Both of these were used throughout the app as they were instantiated in the `Application` class of my app.

I had two viewModels, both of which accept that single `repository` instance as a parameter. The repository returned a `Flow<>` as a return type from one of the functions.

Hence, when one viewModel modifies the database, the other recieves that change since it recieved a `Flow`.

Now I wanted to move away from manual dependency injection and used `Hilt`.

Accidently I forgot to switch one of the viewModels to use the Hilt `provide`ed instance of the repository.

Suddenly the viewmodels were no longer "in sync".

In my understanding and according to the docs, if `Flow` is the return type from a room database, then changes are streamed. And it worked exactly like that, once the database changed, the viewmodel was notifed and the new value was `collect`ed.

Why were they not "in sync" when multiple instances of the repository were used?

It was my understanding as well that room databases are `Singleton`, and so I blamed the repository instance difference. Or is this perhaps related to *caching* the writes ?

Can anyone explain what am I getting wrong in all this?

Edit:

The fix I was referring to is make both viewmodels use the same instance of `repository`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer is that Room is NOT a singleton - you can have multiple instances of it which explains two different sources of truth.

Sources:

- [Kotlin Room Database Singleton Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69654148/kotlin-room-database-singleton-pattern)
- [Using room as singleton in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912619/using-room-as-singleton-in-kotlin)

Comment: Okay so if we assume it is not a singleton , shouldn't the flow be updated everytime the database is updated? because indeed the data _is_ going to a single .db file on the filesystem no matter which instance of Room i use. I think i am missing something.

Comment: Okay I just looked in the docs and found this
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#enableMultiInstanceInvalidation()