# Why use companion object to make singleton in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm studying creation pattern(Singleton pattern) in android kotlin.

I have question about difference in making singleton object by companion object and object.

In some example, singletons are made like this.

```
class ABC {
  companion object {
    private var sInstance: ABC? = null
    
    fun getInstance(): ABC {
        if (sInstance == null) sInstance = ABC()
        return sInstance ?: throw IllegalStateException("")
    }
  }
}
```

but with above method,

```
// a and b are not same object
val a = ABC()
val b = ABC.getInstance()

println(a == b) // false
```

but what I know, singleton in kotlin is just `object`.

So, my question is "Why, When use companion object to make singleton object"

Comment: See the first few sentences of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51835156/2550406). Does that answer your question?

Comment: @lucidbot // I got it, thx very much :)

Answer (score 2):

`getInstance()` is just a "traditional" way of creating singletons. It is a common technique in e.g. Java, because contrary to Kotlin, Java doesn't have singletons provided by the language itself. For this reason you will see `getInstance()` from time to time in Kotlin as well. It may be the code ported from Java, it may be developed by a person who has more experience with Java, so they don't know there is a better alternative in Kotlin, etc.

Additionally, `object` is pretty much static. If we have more complicated logic for creating a singleton, it may be required to create it by some kind of factory (e.g. companion object).

So I would say, the rule of thumb is to use `object` as a default and only if this is not possible, create it manually. And in the latter case, it is more "Kotlin-ish" to use a property, not a `getInstance()` function.