# Can anytime AppDatabase in Android Room be null?

Tags: kotlin, singleton

While adding Room Database, it is suggested to use Singleton Design Pattern

> Note: You should follow the singleton design pattern when instantiating an AppDatabase object, as each RoomDatabase instance is fairly expensive, and you rarely need access to multiple instances.

So, adding Room Database, following Google example which is written in Java, in will be as below

```
private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase? {
    if (INSTANCE == null){
        synchronized(AppDatabase::class){
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                    AppDatabase::class.java, "app_database")
                    .build()
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE
}
```

When I call `getInstance`, compiler suggests that `getInstance` can be `null`. So my question is there any case that `getInstance` be `null` and do I have to check if it's `null`. If not, then how should I instantiate `AppDatabase` so that `getInstance` return `AppDatabase` not `AppDatabase?` and it fits documentation recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this to make sure it is not null

```
object DatabaseSource {
    private lateinit var INSTANCE: AppDatabase

    fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
        if (!::INSTANCE.isInitialized) {
            synchronized(AppDatabase::class) {
                if (!::INSTANCE.isInitialized) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                                                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                                                    "app_database").build()
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE
    }
}
```

Call it with:

```
val db = DatabaseSource.getInstance(context)
```

And this will never be `null` so you no longer have that issue.

I added double locking to be safer for thread safety on the `getInstance()` call.

But really you should be using dependency injection with singletons to avoid this passed in dependency of context and this manual creation/locking. You'll have to have the context available everywhere which is a bad pattern.

This also acts as an answer to [your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53371625/how-to-properly-instantiate-room-database) which is apparently a duplicate of this one.

Comment: That indeed was what I am looking for. But how would I pass the `context` here? Since I am creating INSTANCE in my `companion object`, it's not a good practice to have `context` inside static fields. Looking [google sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicRxJavaSampleKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/observability/persistence/UsersDatabase.kt), I see that they use `also` which works perfectly. What do you say?

Comment: Are you using dependency injection?  because this seems like it should be injected as a singleton, and the context should be made available for injection as well.

Comment: I went with another direction, to make your original sample more workable.

Comment: No I am not injecting as a singleton, but injecting when I call getInstance(context: Context) method.

Comment: I'm suggesting you can use the new version above but you should later move to dependency injection and not have code like this in your app.  Inject context into the AppDatabase building which then is injected into your code as needed.  Not this.  But that is outside the scope of your question.

Comment: I see you point. Your new approach does follow the way I am doing and will also has double locking. However, I read [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40437274/8412192) that I should not use `lateinit` here.

Comment: The comment about not using `lateinit` there is not universally a valid comment.  It is fine in any context where you KNOW the lifecycle gaurantees it will be instantiated before use.  Here the only way to access it is by a method that guarantees it is valid.  So you are fine.  The other comment is not relevant without this context.

Comment: I saw your proposed edit of volatile, but since this is only modified under lock, and we are checking if assigned which is I believe a bit field that would not be partially set.  You can add it if you want, but not sure it is really what you want and will just add more contention on accessing it.

Comment: Let's not add things we see in other posts without reason.