# Save FCM notifications in Room DB in background

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-room

I'm developing an android app that has a Room database and receives notifications with Firebase Cloud Messaging. What I'm trying to implement is a way for the notifications to be saved into the database so the user can see them at any time.

I have accomplished this for notifications that are received while the app is running in the foreground, but not when it's closed.

The code I have is as follows for the messaging service:

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

        private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMessagingServ";
        public static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

        /**
         * Executed when a notification message is received
         * @param remoteMessage
         */
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

            generateNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),
                    remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());


            MyNotificacion noti = new MyNotificacion();
            noti.setTitulo(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
            noti.setContenido(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            //other data

            //Creating the instance here didn't work either
            //MyDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
            //        MyDataBase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
            //        .build();

            MyDatabase db = MyApp.database;
            if (db != null) new InsertNotiAsyncTask(db.getMyNotificacionDao()).execute(noti);
            //all this does is invoking the insert method in the corresponding Dao
        }
        
        //other methods
    }
```

This is my app class:

```
    public class MyApp extends Application {

        public static MyDatabase database;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            database = MyDatabase.getInstance(MyApp.this);
        }
    }
```

And this is the database class:

```
    @Database(entities = {MyNotificacion.class}, version = 1)
    public abstract class MyDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "my_db";

        private static MyDatabase instance;
        public static MyDatabase getInstance(final Context contexto){
            if(instance == null){
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        contexto.getApplicationContext(),
                        MyDatabase.class,
                        DATABASE_NAME
                ).build();
            }
            return instance;
        }

        public abstract MyNotificacionDao getMyNotificacionDao();
    }
```

The main problem is that getting the database instance requires a context. I have followed [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53654053/android-room-avoid-passing-context-into-singleton) as a workaround so I can do this operation from a class that's not an activity, but it simply doesn't work when a notification is received while the app is closed.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

So far I've thought I could maybe save the db instance with shared preferences, but I don't know if it would work, nor does it seem very logical to have persistence for the persistence. Would this be my only other option?

Comment: What [type of Firebase message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) are you sending?  `onMessageReceived()` is not called for a Notification message when the app is in the background.  Send a high-priority data message to wake up a closed app and have `onMessageReceived()` called.

Comment: Thank you so much for calling this to my attention. Turns out I'd been sending notification messages this entire time. I was sure I had it right, but I had implemented that part in my server months ago and it didn't even occur to me that might be the problem. It all works fine now. Thanks again!