# How to initialize the Kotlin Object class with Value upon creation?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have this Java code

```
 public class CrimeLab {
 private static CrimeLab sCrimeLab;
 public static CrimeLab get(Context context) {
     if (sCrimeLab == null) {
     sCrimeLab = new CrimeLab(context);
  }
       return sCrimeLab;
  }
    private CrimeLab(Context context) {
   }
}
```

I am writing this Kotlin Code

```
object CrimeLab {

    }
```

Not sure how to pass "Context" while the object is created for CrimeLab.

Comment: You _can't_ make it an `object`.

Comment: What should be an equivalent Kotlin code?

Comment: Something _equivalent_ just takes everything that's static and puts it in a companion object.  (You're probably better off redesigning things and using dependency injection, but that would require bigger changes.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Singleton with parameter in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398072/singleton-with-parameter-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass arguments as constructor params to object type in kotlin

Right, in kotlin object is singleton but, object has no constructor, but has `init{...}` method which calls when object is just created.

Option: Make optional function like: `fun get(context: Context):CrimeLab { ... return this }`

best solution is pass context to function which need it,

`fun initialize(context: Context) {...}`
...

and in your activity or wherever call like

`CrimeLab.initialize(this)`

**NOTE: do not set context of view instance as a field in object type (singleton), avoid memory leaks.**